# Combine 2 queries with sum involved

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 similar queries that both look like this with only the table being switched from Treatment to Patient in the second query:

```
SELECT Treatment.Phys_ID AS Phys_ID, Physician.FName, Physician.LName, Sum(Treatment.Charge) AS TotCharge 
FROM Physician 
INNER JOIN Treatment ON Physician.Phys_ID = Treatment.Phys_ID
GROUP BY Treatment.Phys_ID, Physician.FName, Physician.LName;
```

The output of both is:

```
Phys_ID___FName___LName____TotCharge
```

When combined, I need to add the 2 queries' columns of TotCharge to get the actual TotCharge. However, when I UNION ALL these 2 queries the tables just stack on top of each other and UNION just rearanges both tables so identical Phys_IDs are next to each other. How can I make the 2 queries' TotCharges add up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries to add the charges at the Physician level:

```
SELECT Physician.Phys_ID AS Phys_ID, Physician.FName, Physician.LName, 

  (SELECT Nz(Sum(Treatment.Charge)) 
   FROM Treatment WHERE Treatment.Phys_ID = Physician.Phys_ID) +

  (SELECT Nz(Sum(Patient.Charge))
   FROM Patient WHERE Patient.Phys_ID = Physician.Phys_ID) As Total Charge

FROM Physician;
```

Alternatively, you can use DSum (strictly an MS Access function and not ANSI SQL).

```
SELECT Physician.Phys_ID AS Phys_ID, Physician.FName, Physician.LName, 

   Nz(DSum("Charge", "Treatment", "Phys_ID =" &  Physician.Phys_ID)) +

   Nz(DSum("Charge", "Patient", "Phys_ID =" & Physician.Phys_ID)) As Total Charge

FROM Physician;
```

Comment: Neither of these work. These are the tables I have. Physician basically has unique key ID, FName and LName. Patient has unique key ID, Physician ID for visit and visit charge. Treatment has physician ID, patient ID and treatment charge. Some physicians only have a visit and no treatment while some treat one patient and have a visit with another

Comment: See my add of Nz() to turn missings to zero so both charges add up properly. But the above should work as subqueries separate the aggregation of Treatments and Patients irregardless of same/different Ts r Ps. Physicians with only Patients will have null (now zero) returned for Treatment sum and vice versa.